# what are the major differences between image asset and bitmap factory plugin

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to resize my image size before uploading it to server. I got to know that one can resize the image by keeping its aspect ratio using image asset. Though the image size was reduced the quality is very poor, and one more option i found is bitmap factory.

So, by using bitmap does the image quality is better than using image asset. kindly clarify this. Since the plugin is giving lot of errors currently. i don't want to waste time solving those if i don't get better quality images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to resizing the image, both image-asset module and bitmap factory plugin does the same job.

Apart from resizing, the bitmap factory plugin also allows you to draw objects / write text over image. I'm not sure how it makes you a difference with image quality, but if you check the code it is almost the same for resizing.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with both image resizing, and i don't know why i see some

> better quality image from bitmap than image asset

. you can check yourself with this below code.

**For Bitmap**

```
    let w = imageSourceModule.fromFile(img).width;
    let h = imageSourceModule.fromFile(img).height;
    var bmp = BitmapFactory.create(w, h);
    const asset_1 = new ImageAsset(img);
    imageSourceModule.fromAsset(asset_1)
        .then(img_1 => {
            bmp.dispose(function (b) {
                b.insert(BitmapFactory.makeMutable(img_1));
                // ## Max dimension. Respects aspect ratio.
                var b2 = b.resizeMax(250);
                var thumb_image = b2.toImageSource();
                console.log("-----thumb_image------");
                console.log(thumb_image);
                if (thumb_image) {
                    console.log("bit map File successfully deleted....!");
                    thumb_image.saveToFile(pathDest_1, "jpg");
                }
            });
        })
```

**For Image Asset**

```
 const asset = new ImageAsset(img);
    asset.options = {
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        keepAspectRatio: true,
        autoScaleFactor: true,
    };
 imageSourceModule.fromAsset(asset)
        .then(img => {
            img.saveToFile(pathDest, "jpg");

        })
```